# aws certificate being used by unkown cloudfront instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I need to update/delete my certificate in the aws certificate manager. However when i try to do so, it says my certificate is being used by

`Associated resources
arn:aws:cloudfront::<my-user-id>:distribution/ABC`

However, when i navigate to the cloudfront section, there is no cloudfront distribution with that arn.

Does anyone experienced something similiar and knows how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is it possible that you formerly had a CloudFront distribution with that ID that you deleted?  I believe there is or was a bug in the integration between the two services where CloudFront didn't send the appropriate message to ACM when a distro was deleted, to release the claim on the cert.

Comment: ...or, this *might* be related to API Gateway using the cert, which in some cases creates a CloudFront distribution that is not visible in the CloudFront console.  Are you using API Gateway?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes i did a lot of creating/removing of cloudfront distributions as i was playing around with terraform. Do you know how to resolve this bug?